# DNX Codegeneration for empty controller throws Method not found exception

Tags: asp.net, dnx

I am using VS2015 with DNX 1.0.0-beta6 for my application and am trying to use command line codegeneration to generate an empty controller and am encountering the following error. Need assistance.

```
d:\Project>dnx . gen controller -name PersonController
Finding the generator 'controller'...
Running the generator 'controller'...
Method not found: 'Microsoft.AspNet.Razor.GeneratorResults Microsoft.AspNet.Razor.RazorTemplateEngine.GenerateCode(System.IO.TextReader)'
```

My project.json looks like this

```
{
  "webroot": "wwwroot",
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-beta6",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta6",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-beta6",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta6",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta6",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta6",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-beta6",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-beta6",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Logging": "1.0.0-beta6",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-beta6",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-beta6",
    "EntityFramework.Core": "7.0.0-beta6",
    "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-beta6",
    "EntityFramework.SqlServer": "7.0.0-beta6",
    "Microsoft.Framework.CodeGeneration": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.Framework.CodeGenerators.Mvc": "1.0.0-beta5"
  },
  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --config hosting.ini",
    "gen": "Microsoft.Framework.CodeGeneration",
    "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {
      "dependencies": {
        "EntityFramework.Core": "7.0.0-beta5"
      }
    },
    "dnxcore50": { }
  },
  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "**.xproj",
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "npm install", "bower install", "gulp clean", "gulp min" ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `beta5` of the `Microsoft.Framework.CodeGeneration` and `Microsoft.Framework.CodeGenerators.Mvc`, as they depend on beta5 infrastructure that will conflict with the other dependencies you have.

At this moment beta6 for these packages have not yet been published or released.

There is a github issue tracking that:

https://github.com/aspnet/Scaffolding/issues/105

When this is answered we will know if it will be fixed or not.

At this moment, to use scaffolding you have to go back to `beta5`.

**Update:** Another option is to use the `aspnetmaster` feed: https://www.myget.org/gallery/aspnetmaster

Comment: This is still true in beta7, the package can still be obtained from the myget feed.